# Kotlin Coroutine Main Looper Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have been studying the coroutines and their applications in Android when a natural question came into my mind. Why don’t we use a non-blocking implementation of Main Looper that processes the message queue inside the main coroutine so that we could use suspending functions in any part of the application without explicitly launching new coroutines?

I’m nowhere near an expert in coroutines, but I think that such enhancement could potentially be useful, even though may require a complete revision of the Android’s platform code.

Comment: Because coruotines aren't magic.  If you start to have various functions finish at random times, you lose determinism.  Losing that makes a lot of things very hard, if not impossible.  That's why so many things happen on the main thread-  so that the order is deterministic and you can know for sure that onStart finishes before onResume, that onMeasure finishes before you draw, that touch input is handled relative to the state of the UI when the touch occurred rather than handling it on its own thread when the UI may have changed, etc.

Comment: @GabeSechan very thoughtful reply, thanks! You can put it as an answer, I will accept it if no one else goes into more detail

Comment: You lose that ordering whenever you apply coroutines, so I'm not really happy with this argumentation. A function suspends itself for a reason, because it can't go on at the moment. It would indeed be more convenient if all android callbacks were `suspend fun`s to begin with, but i don't think that's going to happen. You'd first have to eliminate Java from the picture.

Comment: Let me also note that I don't like the default behavior of `launch(UI)`, it delays even the coroutine start so you lose ordering right at the top. That's why i use `start = UNDISPATCHED` in my project. Sometimes i must also use `with(myContinuation) { UI.resumeUndispatched(Unit) }`  to resume synchronously, within the event handler frame.